# Can't run 'sudo cordova build android'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I create new app hello world and add android platform, and when I run sudo cordova build android
It show error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/33.0.3
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/v002024/Documents/cordova/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 33.0.2.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

My zshrc file:

```
export PATH="/Users/v002024/FlutterDev/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export JAVA_HOME="/Users/v002024/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_382/Contents/Home"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/v002024/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/v002024/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

and when I try 'echo $ANDROID_HOME' or 'echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' in Visual studio code it return exactyl path in zshrc.

SDK tools 33.0.2 installed

[image]
[image]

I have emulator Nexus 6 API 33

[image]

How I can run my project?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you see this: > No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 33.0.2?

Comment: @tomerpacific yep, Id flow https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/13120 and add PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools, I have android emulator Nexus 6 Api 33